# How to do long lived tokens with Katana OAuth Bearer Tokens

Tags: oauth, owin, katana

From the SPA template i managed to get basic OAuth flows working.

```
    OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
    {
        AllowInsecureHttp = true, 
        ApplicationCanDisplayErrors = true,
        TokenEndpointPath = new Microsoft.Owin.PathString("/Token"),
        AuthorizeEndpointPath = new Microsoft.Owin.PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
        Provider = new CompositeWebroleOauthProvider<User>(PublicClientId, IdentityManagerFactory, CookieOptions)
    };
```

I have a single page application that is hosted on a seperate domain that will interact with the webapi using the bearer tokens from the Token endpoint.

I am doing the ResourceOwnerCredentials flow, with a request with the following data:

```
 data: {
        grant_type: "password",
        username: username,
        password: password
       }
```

These tokens are short lived ect. I now would like to extend my application such I can get a refress token or something such I do not have to authenticate all the time.
What is my next steps?

The GrantResourceOwnerCredentials implementation:

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
{
    using (var identityManager = _identityManagerFactory.Create())
    {
        var user = await identityManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);

        if (user == null)
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
            return;
        }               

        ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await identityManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, context.Options.AuthenticationType);
        AuthenticationProperties properties = CreatePropertiesAsync(user);
        AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);
        context.Validated(ticket);

    }
}
```

Comment: On the line    AuthenticationProperties     properties = CreatePropertiesAsync(user);    what does your CreatePropertiesAsync method look like?

Comment: Its some time ago, not sure where the code got parked.  But my work was around the stuff that got published here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/09/20/understanding-security-features-in-spa-template.aspx which also uses it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to set the provider for it to generate refresh tokens.

Any comments for pointers on when to set refresh tokens and not would be nice.

```
 RefreshTokenProvider = new AuthenticationTokenProvider
 {
     OnCreate = CreateRefreshToken,
     OnReceive = ReceiveRefreshToken,
 }


    private void CreateRefreshToken(AuthenticationTokenCreateContext context)
    {
        context.SetToken(context.SerializeTicket());
    }

    private void ReceiveRefreshToken(AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext context)
    {
        context.DeserializeTicket(context.Token);
    }
```

Comment: Basically RefreshToken helps the application get a new AccessToken even after curent AccessToken is expired. While getting the new AccessToken, the RefreshToken can be presented and need not required username-password. RefreshToken lifetime can be managed by Token Provider and user should be provided with option to grant lifetime of RefreshToken.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. Just need to figure out how to do that in Katana AuthorizationServer (Owin). Seems the refresh tokens get same lifetime as the access tokens.

Comment: Yes, refresh token is created from the same ticket as the accessToken ticket. We can change it via ServerOptions provided at startup as you have noted above.

Comment: But that means we change both refresh and access token. Would I not want something like the access token having 20 min and refresh token until revoked?

Comment: For accessToken, you can pass AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan. Yes, you can keep the refreshtoken with longer timespan.

Comment: Thank you for your answers here and in the other question with the same. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19409085/lifetime-of-refresh-tokens-with-katana-oauthauthorizationserver/19421929?noredirect=1#comment28798768_19421929