# Lifetime of Refresh Tokens with Katana OAuthAuthorizationServer

Tags: oauth, owin, katana

From the source code sandbox Webserver, refresh tokens was done like this:

```
RefreshTokenProvider = new AuthenticationTokenProvider
{
    OnCreate = CreateRefreshToken,
    OnReceive = ReceiveRefreshToken,
}

private void CreateRefreshToken(AuthenticationTokenCreateContext context)
{
    context.SetToken(context.SerializeTicket());
}

private void ReceiveRefreshToken(AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext context)
{
    context.DeserializeTicket(context.Token);
}
```

This create refresh tokens that have the same lifetime as the access tokens.

What would be appropriate lifetime for a refresh token and what would be the suggested way of telling that to the OAuthAuthorizationServer.  Theres no options for it, and I am wondering if I should just change it on the ticket in the context of above createRefreshToken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What would be appropriate lifetime for a refresh token

Its all dependent on use-case. RefreshToken lifetime can be based on the application requirement. Google oAuth has "Refresh tokens are valid until the user revokes access".

> what would be the suggested way of telling that to the OAuthAuthorizationServer.

Yes, you are right for the approach. you can set it to Tiken in the context.

```
private void CreateRefreshToken(AuthenticationTokenCreateContext context)
{
    context.Ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(2));
    context.SetToken(context.SerializeTicket());
}
```

Comment: Okay. thanks. And if I wanted to do like google to have it infinite until revoked. I would just add the logic into the CreateRefreshToken ?

Comment: Yes, you need to maintain those token table to verify its lifetime attach each to a user and allow the user to revoke. You can keep the revoked record or just remove it at the revocation.